# Simple PHP select option programming

Tags: php

I have a simple problem in php select option.

The page has 5 select option & submit button. When I select a option then it should goes on specific web page. For Example: http://onlinetools.org/tricks/using_multiple_select.php

Then I select a option & press Send then It show Which option I select. But I need go specific webpage.

I have tried with this code but I have failed...

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<select name="test[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="http://google.com">one</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">two</option>
    <option value="http://facebook.com">three</option>
    <option value="http://who.is">four</option>
    <option value="http://myspace.com">five</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>




<?php
    $test=$_POST['test'];
echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
window.location = \"$test\"
</script>

    ";
?>
```

Anybody Can help me?

Comment: Please don't use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Just leave the action empty. e.g. `method="post" action=""`

Comment: Why does your select box have `multiple="multiple"` when only one option at a time can make sense?  Similarly, why have it be `test[]`, when you're not treating it like an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be a simple select not a multiple one since you want to redirect to only one site. here is the code :

```
<?php
    $test=$_POST['test'];
    if(isset($test)){
        header("Location: $test");
    }
?>

<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
<select name="test">
    <option value="http://google.com">one</option>
    <option value="http://yahoo.com">two</option>
    <option value="http://facebook.com">three</option>
    <option value="http://who.is">four</option>
    <option value="http://myspace.com">five</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: `PHP_SELF` is vulnerable, consider leaving it empty.

Comment: I left it untouched since I figured he is using this as a test script.  but you are right, thx for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

As you've declared:

```
<select name="test[]" multiple="multiple">
```

`test` is an array, thus you have to take the first object of the array or remove the unused `[]`. By the way, you can do an HTTP redirection, which is faster and works more often than javascript ones.